# Unable to center map on a specific location

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, mapkit

I'm trying to center a map on a custom location with the following code:

```
mapView = new MapKit.MKMapView();

mapView.ZoomEnabled = true;
mapView.ScrollEnabled = true;

mapDelegate = new GeoFleet.iOS.MapDelegate();
mapView.Delegate = mapDelegate;

var region = new MapKit.MKCoordinateRegion(
new CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.6114099, longitude: 7.0817283), 
    new MapKit.MKCoordinateSpan(0.00899321605918731, 0.0124209769840958)
                        );
this.mapView.Region = region;
```

Unfortunately, this displays me the map of France; not the country's south east location I'm requesting.

How can I debug this kind of problem?

EDIT:

You can go to the location with the following [link](https://www.google.com/maps/place/43%C2%B036%2741.1%22N+7%C2%B004%2754.2%22E/@43.6114138,7.0795396,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d43.6114099!4d7.0817283).

I've tried this other call which does neither work:

```
MapKit.MKCoordinateRegion.FromDistance(new CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.6114099, longitude: 7.0817283), 2000, 2000);
```

Comment: have you tried different values for MKCoordinateSpan?

Comment: @nilsK commas are a copy/paste typo, sorry.

Comment: @Jason See edit.

Comment: I tried setting the region to your values in a test app and it worked fine for me.  Is there anything in your delegate that might interfering?  Where in your code is this executing?

Comment: @Jason No there is nothing in the delegate right now. The code is executing in response to a button touch. What bothers me is that even in the device log there is nothing telling that something is wrong as will be the result.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    MKMapView map;
    UIButton btn;

    public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        map = new MKMapView(this.View.Bounds);

        this.View.AddSubview(map);

        btn = new UIButton(UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
        btn.SetTitle("GO!!!",UIControlState.Normal);
        btn.TouchDown += Btn_TouchDown;
        btn.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(100,200,50,50);
        
        this.View.AddSubview(btn);
    }

    private void Btn_TouchDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.map.Region = new MapKit.MKCoordinateRegion(
          new CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.6114099, longitude: 7.0817283),
new MapKit.MKCoordinateSpan(0.00899321605918731, 0.0124209769840958)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your iOS/Phone version ? Should Have posted some pictures before... I just updated my iPhone SE (2nd Gen) to iOS 14.6 and it works :(